# Is CMS Replication required for ApplicationPool also?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, ucma, lync-server-2010

Is CMS Replication required for ApplicationPool also?

When I run the command `Get-CsManagementStoreReplicationStatus` I get `UpToDate : True` for my domain but it comes `False` for my ApplicationPool.

```
UpToDate           : True
ReplicaFqdn        : ****.*****
LastStatusReport   : 07-08-2014 11:42:26
LastUpdateCreation : 07-08-2014 11:42:26
ProductVersion     : 5.0.8308.0

UpToDate           : False
ReplicaFqdn        : MyApplicationPool.****.*****
LastStatusReport   :
LastUpdateCreation : 08-08-2014 15:16:03
ProductVersion     :

UpToDate           : False
ReplicaFqdn        : ****.*****
LastStatusReport   :
LastUpdateCreation : 08-08-2014 15:10:59
```

Am I on the right track? Have I created my ApplicationPool wrongly?

Comment: please note that i didnt get ProductVersion for my ApplicationPool.

Comment: when i run **New-CsTrustedApplicationPool -Identity -Registrar -Site -CompterFqdn** i get this warning _"WARNING: Missing Computer The following machines from the topology you are publishing were not found in Active Directory and will result in errors during Enable-CsTopology when it tries to prepare Active Directory entries for the topology machines. If you choose to publish this topology, you must run Enable-CsTopology again after you join the missing machines to the domain:"_ but the pool is created successfully, is this warning d reason why i am not able to achive replication ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, UCMA applications running on an app server generally require access to the CMS, so replication should be enabled.

On the app server, you'd need to:

- Ensure the "Lync Server Replica Replicator Agent" service is running
- Run Enable-CsReplica in the management shell
- Run Enable-CsTopoloy
- Then run Invoke-CSManagementStoreReplication to force a replication

I've noticed that it often takes a while for the CMS to be replicated to the app server, so you might need to run Get-CsManagementStoreReplicationStatus a few times before you see UpToDate change to True.

Comment: I followed the steps you mentioned, but still i was not able to get UpToDate to True, However i will like to point out that while executing the powershell command: New-CsTrustedApplicationPool -Identity -ComputerFqdn -Registrar -Site , i got an error for -ComputerFqdn    
 New-CsTrustedApplicationPool : There is a duplicate key sequence 'My.Server.Fqdn.Hidden' for the 'urn:schema:Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Deploy.Topology.2008:MachineFqdn' key or unique identity constraint.

 so i ignored -ComputerFqdn parameter, so is the replication not happening due to this ?

Comment: I don't honestly know, and it's a now a bit beyond the scope of a development issue. Maybe someone on ServerFault.com could help out?

Comment: i did some searching around it, came across [this link](http://rcosic.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/provisioning-ucma-applications/) where it says "You’ll have to add a new Host (A) entry on your DC machine, with the same IP address as your Lync server machine, representing the ‘fake app pool’ machine." is its really necessary ?

Comment: By the sounds of it, Ratko is deploying his app to a machine running one of the standard Lync server roles, e.g. a front end server (rather than creating a dedicated App Server). Microsoft discourage this, but it is possible. If you're also doing the same thing, then I'd say yes, you need to add the A record.

Comment: i am doing the same thing, i have now created a new host which pings back to my lync server, but still i am unable to get UpToDate value to True

Comment: ApplicationPool of the same machine replication works for me and now i am able to run Auto-Provisioned Applications also, but still dont know what was the problem with Fake Host Replication.